# What's the correct way to generate random strings without duplicates

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I'm thinking about generating random strings, without making any duplication.

First thought was to use a binary tree  create and locate for duplicate in tree, if any.
  But this may not be very effective.

Second thought was using MD5 like hash method  which create messages based only on time, but this may introduce another problem, different machines has different accuracy of time.
And in a modern processor, more than one string could be created in a single timestamp.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: How different do you need your strings to be?  How many do you need?  For instance, generate a string one letter short of the required length, and add each letter a-z in turn to the end.  That guarantees 26 non-identical strings, but I doubt if that algorithm will meet your needs.

Comment: There's been a joke around on this topic: get some students, give them a Vi console and tell them to exit.

Comment: How long can your strings be?  How many of them will you need to generate?  What are the repercussions of a duplicate occurring (expensive or unacceptable)?  Can the nodes that generate these strings communicate with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate N sequential strings, then do a [random shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to pull them out in random order.    If they need to be unique across separate generators,  mix a unique generator ID into the string.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of MD5, there's no guarantee that two different Strings won't generate the same hash.

As for your problem, it depends on a number of constraints: are the strings short or long? Do they have to be meaningful? Etc... Two solutions from the top of my head:

1 Generate [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) then turn them into String with a binary representation or base 64 algorithm.

2 Simply generate random Strings and put them in a searchable structure (HashMap) so that you can find very quickly (O(1)-O(log n)) if a generated String already has a duplicate, in which case it is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

A tree probably won't be the most efficient, especially for insertions - as it will have to constantly re-balance itself (somewhat of an "expensive" operation).

I'd recommend using a `HashSet` type data structure.  The hashing algorithm should already be quite efficient (much more so than something like MD5), and all operations are constant-time.  Insert all your Strings into the Set.  If you create a new String, check to see if it already exists in the Set.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to generate a uuid? See http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html

```
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('dafd3cb8-3163-4734-906b-a33671ce52fe')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify in what programming language you're coding. For instance, in Java this will work nicely: `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` . [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) identifiers are unique in practice, as is stated in wikipedia:

> The intent of UUIDs is to enable distributed systems to uniquely identify information without significant central coordination. In this context the word unique should be taken to mean "practically unique" rather than "guaranteed unique". Since the identifiers have a finite size it is possible for two differing items to share the same identifier. The identifier size and generation process need to be selected so as to make this sufficiently improbable in practice.

Answer (score 0):

A binary tree is probably better than usual here - no rebalancing necessary, because your strings are random, and it's on random data that binary trees work their best.  However, it's still O(log(n)) for lookup and addition.

But maybe more efficient, if you know in advance how many random strings you'll need and don't mind a little probability in the mix, is to use a bloom filter.

Bloom filters give an efficient, probabilistic set membership test with memory requirements as low as one bit per element saved in the set.  Basically, a bloom filter can say with 100% certainty that a member does not belong to a set, but with a high but not quite 100% certainty that a member is in a set.  In your case, throwing out an extra candidate or two shouldn't hurt at all, so the probabilistic nature shouldn't hurt a bit.

Bloom filters are also relatively unique in that they can test for set membership in constant time.

For a while, I listed treaps here, but that's silly - they do a lot of operations in O(log(n)) again, and would only be relevant if your data isn't truly random.

If you don't need your strings to be saved in order for some reason (and it sounds like you probably don't), a traditional hash table is a good way to go.  They like to know how big your final dataset will be in advance (to avoid slow hash table resizes), but they too are constant time for insertion and lookup.

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/bloom-filter/trunk/